# Using the header function for PHP files?

Tags: php, forms

Why would we need to place this at the top of your PHP scripts? Should we only use it if we have an HTML file with some PHP elements in it?

```
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

I have a form built in HTML but the file itself is in PHP.

Comment: we should always indicate content-type and charset of any file produced by php script, as we cannot rely on default settings

Comment: easier to do it via Apache, then you only set it once.

Comment: all you're doing is telling the receiving end what you're sending. a PHP script USUALLY sends html, but not always.

Answer (score 1):

Some browsers don't just assume the page is html when there is no header, so to get your page to work right in them you have to send a header.

And, obviously, if you are using UTF8 you need to specify that, so that's why you would send this header.

And, of course, headers can be used to specify other types of files will be returned by our php code, like PDF, Excel, CSV, etc.

Comment: So if I have a form that is built in HTML but saved as a PHP file, I should place this at the top of the form in this format? `<?php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); ?>` Also, does this mean I would need to place it in my scripts as well? Luckily all the data I am saving with the form is written into files and not returned to the users, so I won't need a bunch of different headers.

Comment: @LoudGraveyard, You're confusing file extension with content type. Your file is a php file, but what are you returning to the browser content-wise? HTML code, so the content type should be text/html. You could return XML from your php code, and the content type would be text/xml, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Versions of PHP prior to 5.6 didn't specify `charset=utf-8` by default. This can cause rendering issues if you use non-ASCII characters in UTF-8 and the browser doesn't detect the encoding correctly.